# php думает что input пустой когда использую атрибут list

Tags: php, html, mysql, input

Возможно такой вопрос уже был но я его не нашел.
php думает что input пустой когда использую атрибут list
вот код input-а:

```
<div>
<?php
  $qr_result = mysql_query("SELECT Culture FROM  `table2`")
  or die(mysql_error());
  while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){
echo '<input name="Culture" list="Culture" size="20">';
echo '<datalist id="Culture">';
echo '<option>' . $data['Culture'] . '</option>';
  }
?><br />
```

код проверки пустого input-a:

```
if(empty($_POST['Culture'])){
 echo '<div class="box5">';
echo '<h3>Вы не ввели данные</h3>';
echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: а где <form> у вас?

Comment: <form> стоит выше я просто не вставил его сюда

Comment: у вас эти инпуты в цикле выводятся. имя у них одинаковое. на сервер при отправке прийдет только последнее значение (последнего инпута). может он таки пуст? вообще не ясно что это такое и как  сие работает. вы посмотрите сначала какую оно верстку генерит.